# angular module multiple dependancy using modernizr

Tags: angularjs, modernizr

I am using 'Modernizr' for detecting mobile devices.I have created 'touchevent.js' file for the mobile devices

In touchevent.js

```
`var touchApp = angular.module('ngTouchEvent', [])
```

In script.js

```
'var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngTouchEvent' ]);
```

now I want to load touchevent.js only in mobile devices using modernizr.
I am using

> Modernizr.load('touchevent.js');

I am facing problem like

> [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp

in other than mobile device.

I dont want to load touchevent.js in desktop.Can I have solution for multiple dependacy

Comment: touchevent.js , you could make it as service

Comment: This is one example.In multiple scenario according to device width and type (ios,IE) i have to restrict all js loading.I want load require files but problem with dependancy injection

Comment: Means you want to load your js file only when required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Modernizr is an javascript object which you can use directly in any angular controller or directive without specifying any dependency on angular app. You can create an provider like this to use Modernizr in controller or directive like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').provider('Modernizr', function() {
    this.$get = function() {
        return Modernizr || {};
    };
});

Modernizr.mq()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this project which offer a base project for using AngularJS with RequireJS to load on demand the required js files.

https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed

If your application is huge, it might be useful, otherwise it can be overkill because just the fact of using AngularJS reduce the amount of code to be written.

Hoping it will be helpful